# How to convert all directory mp3 files in a subdirectory with lame using bash?

Tags: bash, lame

I'm using git bash in Windows 8.1 and I have lame installed. My git is in my Laravel directory. For 1 conversion  I use :

```
/c/Lame/lame --mp3input -V2 -b 64 public/songs/album/album_1000/song_Emmene-moi_1379645693.mp3 public/songs/album/album_1000/64kb/song_Emmene-moi_1379645693.mp3
```

Which works great. But when I want to convert all at once I try :

```
for file in public/songs/album/album_1000/*.mp3; 
do /c/Lame/lame --mp3input -b 64 "$file" 64kb/"${file%.*}".mp3; done
```

I get error :

Can't init outfile '64kb/public/songs/album/album_1000/song_Bagay 9 (Remix)_1379645802.mp3'
Can't init outfile '64kb/public/songs/album/album_1000/song_Bootleg_1379645790.mp3'
Can't init outfile '64kb/public/songs/album/album_1000/song_Emmene-moi_1379645693.mp3'
...

I need to add them in a subdirectory called 64kb like public/songs/album/album_1000/64kb/song_Emmene-moi_1379645693.mp3

This is to use later in PHP code, I will have variable for album, album_1000 and the mp3 song name, so any string replace on album_1000/ to album_1000/64kb/ will be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests I get it to work with the internal string replacement pattern

```
{$Var//string_to_replace/new_string} :

$ for file in public/songs/album/album_1000/*.mp3;
do /c/Lame/lame --mp3input -b 64 "$file" "${file//album_1000/album_1000/64kb}"; done
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an absolute path starting with a / or it won't work.  This solved it running on my mac anyway.  It was not a folder permissions issue as some other related posts online mention.

Comment: My problem at this time was not the path nor permission. It was because I wanted to move all the converted files in a subdirectory like `64kb`, `128kb`, `192kb` etc. It was from a variable that I could inject with PHP because it was a Lame operation, so Lame should inject that subdirectory. So Instead having Lame ouput them to `64kb/public/songs/album/album_1000/`, Lame should do it in `public/songs/album/album_1000/64kb/`. So I made Lame replace `album_1000` with `album_1000/64kb` and it solved it. I'm using Mac now for DEV, and it's working the same way. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just thought I might be able to help some folks who may have the "can't init file" error in the future...